# Python: How to check if JSON item exists?

Tags: python, json

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "information": {
        "age": "20",
        "height": "6'0",
        "fav_quote": "age is just a number",
        "sports": [
          "soccer",
          "basketball",
          "baseball",
          "football",
          "hockey"
        ], 

        ...

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I get this information with `info = json.loads(myjsonthatsabove)` how do I check if 'age' exists, because the information in the json can be different and not always have that. How can I check if `sports[3]` (football) exists, or find out how many items are in the sports array?

```
if 'age' in info['data'][0]['information']:
    //code
```

works to check if age is there, but is this checking all of ['information'], so for example if ['fav_quote'] had 'age' in it it would work? How can I check this information?

Comment: just like any other dictionary with lists in it

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if sports[3] (football) exists
>   or find out how many items are in the sports array?

Use `len(object)`, did you read the doc?

```
for item in info['data']:
    print '%s is practicing %d sport(s)' % (
        item['name'],
        len(item['information']['sports']),
    )
```